# Codeigniter using the same form to save and edit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the same view in `CodeIgniter` to save and edit. Successfully completed the saving functionality, when using the same form to edit the user. I am getting the error

> Message: Undefined variable lastname

```
<form>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" value="<?php echo $user->lastname; ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: How do you load the view? Looks like the `$user` object doesn't have any property `lastname`

Comment: You can use just `value="<?=@$user->$lastname; ?>"` will not generate error

Comment: Gopal that worked , thanks man. Is there any other method with out suppress, i don't know whether it is recommended . with the supperssor it is working fine! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$last_name=NULL;
if(isset($user->lastname)){
$last_name=$user->lastname;
}

?>


<form>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last name" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">
</form>
```

I hope this will work

Comment: while this suppresses the error, it should be places within controller's method, not within a template

Comment: hi this is good , in my controller code  $data['user'] =  $this->user_model->getUser();

Comment: This will work , i have test it in the view , But the issues is when we have 10 fields for user , in the edit section we should have to write check before feeding the value to the input fields.

Comment: Yeah.. you have to check before feeding, then only you won't get errors or else you have to intialize all the values of that object in constructor.. so when you get user data if the given parameters values not existed, you will get empty

Comment: intialize all the values of that object in constructor is a good option devi

Answer (score 0):

Populate the saved value in the view , while fetching from the database.
And the while your insert is happening check for same value existed in the db, if value exists in db=>use update else insert

Comment: that is no the case santhosh, we have to use the same form for saving and editing. when the cod to load the value on edit is embed , when u load the save form it promps error as the value undefined. this is beacuse reusing the same form .